# Wix UI difference between Edit Control and MaskedEdit Control

Tags: wix, installation

anyone has any idea that the UI appearance difference between Edit Control and MaskedEdit Control?

[image]

How could I made them look like the same?

Answer (score 2):

A long time since the question was answered, but for anyone else that stumbles onto this...

The best i could do was to make the control slightly smaller and set the `sunken` property to true:

```
<Control Id="ServerPort" Type="MaskedEdit" Height="17" Width="30" Property="DATABASE_PORT" Text="#####" Sunken="yes" />
```

[image]

Would be interested to know if there is a better way by now.